# Why does gcc can't find opencv.hpp file?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm quite new to *CMake*, but I want to build a test `.cpp` file that includes *OpenCV* and shows me an image. I have built *OpenCV* in the path `/usr/local` and I have here folder with *opencv.hpp* file - `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp`.  Here is my *CMakeLists.txt* file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(cpp_proj)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_executable(cpp_proj opencv_cpp.cpp)

include_directories(${OPENCV4_INCLUDES})
target_link_libraries(cpp_proj )
```

I opened `~./bashrc` and added there lines:

```sh
export OPENCV4_INCLUDES=/usr/local/include/
export OPENCV4_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/lib/

export PATH=$PATH:$OPENCV4_LIBRARIES
export PATH=$PATH:$OPENCV4_INCLUDES
```

When I run `cmake` in bash - everything is ok and even *find_package* finds *OpenCV*. But when I'm trying to run `make` it gives me a error:

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/cpp_proj/build $ cmake ..
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/Desktop/cpp_proj/build
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/cpp_proj/build $ make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cpp_proj.dir/opencv_cpp.cpp.o
/home/pi/Desktop/cpp_proj/opencv_cpp.cpp:1:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_proj.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/cpp_proj.dir/opencv_cpp.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/cpp_proj.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I found questions with the same problem, but they didn't help me. What I am doing wrong? What could be the reason of this? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `OPENCV4_INCLUDES` be `/usr/local/include/opencv4/` ?

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for the answer! But I even tried this. I tried lots of path variants, but they do not help

Comment: Use `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` instead of `OPENCV4_INCLUDES` and roll back the `bashrc` changes.

Comment: @u-235 Thanks! That worked, but now I have other errors when I *make* like ```undefined reference to `cv::imread```

Comment: try this: `target_link_libraries(cpp_proj PUBLIC OpenCV)`

Comment: @eliottness, this returned the error ```/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCV``` when I tried to *make*

Comment: What about `target_link_libraries(cpp_proj ${OpenCV_LIBS})`?

Comment: @u-235 That worked! Thanks to everyone! Now I don't have error while using cmake but there are some troubles with opencv so I should re-install raspbian image, because I mixed up some things there. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use a library you must specify the include directory as well as the libs.

With find_package (in module mode), in your case it should populate the variables OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS and OpenCV_LIBS for you to use.

So I recommend to add / alter your code to add the include directory & link the library (such as below)

```
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} public ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} public ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I don't believe you ever need to touch ~./bashrc when using find_package